# Pass the value of a variable from child component to two parent components, vuejs? nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

How to store the state value of a variable?

For example, I have three components: `home.vue` and `map.vue`, as well as a common `sidebar.vue` component, which is used inside `home.vue` and `map.vue`.

I pass some data from `sidebar.vue` (a variable storing sidebar width state). And this data should change dynamically in both components. That is, when switching from `home.vue` to `map.vue`, the state of the variable for changing the width of `sidebar.vue` should not change.

Comment: You are a new contributor and welcome, but this not how you ask a question. You should not ask for a whole project or code. You should work around it some by yourself. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the width of the sidebar in [Vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

Create the store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    width: 50
  },
  mutations: {
    setWidth (state, value) {
      state.width = value
    }
  }
})
```

"Inject" the store into all child components from the root component with the store option (enabled by Vue.use(Vuex)):

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // provide the store using the "store" option.
  // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
  store,
  ...
})
```

By providing the store option to the root instance, the store will be injected into all child components of the root and will be available on them as `this.$store`. When the width is changed update it by calling mutation method in the methods of your components:

```
this.$store.commit('setWidth', value)
```

To read the value of the `width` from the store in any method of your vue-components use this:

```
this.$store.state.width
```